# How to create Ajax request that gets information as the servlet runs?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a form that creates an account and a servlet that handles the request.

However, the process to create this account is a long process and I want to create something like a status bar or a progress bar. Heres the POST:

> $.post("createAccount.jsp", function(data) { $("#status").text(data);
>   });

And the servlet would continuously print data like "creating x..." then "creating y" as the servlet runs. Is there a way to accomplish this or maybe another way to tackle this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You need to poll your server using AJAX requests. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Comment: [This will help](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Http works on a `request-response` model. You send a request, and server responds back. After that Server doesn't know who are you?!

> It's like Server is a post-office that doesn't know your address. You
>   go to it and get your letters.It doesn't come to your home for
>   delivering letters.

If you want constant notifications from server, You can either use [Web Sockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/)(Stack Overflow also uses Web Sockets) or use `AJAX Polling' mechanisms,

> which sends an AJAX request to the server and waits for server to
>   respond. On retrieval of response,it generates another AJAX request
>   and keep on doing the same until server stops generating new data.

[Read this for an explanation of AJAX Polling techniques](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could have your account creation servlet update a database or context attribute as it creates the account.

You could have a separate AJAX request to a different servlet that sends back to the webpage the most recent development found in the database or context attribute. You would then poll your server with that AJAX request every so many fractions of a second(or relevant time interval depending on how long of a task it is to create an account) to get all the updates.